# Returning a dynamically specified number of images from an Adapter

Tags: android, arrays, image, gridview, baseadapter

I am using a custom ImageAdapter with a GridView in order to display a 4*4 set of images.
I am wanting to be able to pass the number of images to be returned by the adapter dynamically, the tutorials/questions i've seen so far all are based on a preset number of images e.g. Only return the first 30. I'm not sure how to implement a method that takes an int and returns that many images from the array. Any help would be appreciated. Many Thanks

This is what i have so far that returns all the images to the grid view.

ImageAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;    
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mMona = {
        R.drawable.joconde_1_1, R.drawable.joconde_1_2, R.drawable.joconde_1_3,R.drawable.joconde_1_4,
        R.drawable.joconde_2_1, R.drawable.joconde_2_2, R.drawable.joconde_2_3,R.drawable.joconde_2_4,
        R.drawable.joconde_3_1, R.drawable.joconde_3_2, R.drawable.joconde_3_3,R.drawable.joconde_3_4,
        R.drawable.joconde_4_1, R.drawable.joconde_4_2, R.drawable.joconde_4_3,R.drawable.joconde_4_4,
};

public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mMona.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mMona[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mMona[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Activity class

```
 ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take an int array as argument for Image Adapter. That array has position of required of image in your Images Array, make an temp array or Image to be returned. I have not tested it but i think i should work.
changed code is here..

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;    
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    Integer []retuning;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mMona = {
        R.drawable.joconde_1_1, R.drawable.joconde_1_2, R.drawable.joconde_1_3,R.drawable.joconde_1_4,
        R.drawable.joconde_2_1, R.drawable.joconde_2_2, R.drawable.joconde_2_3,R.drawable.joconde_2_4,
        R.drawable.joconde_3_1, R.drawable.joconde_3_2, R.drawable.joconde_3_3,R.drawable.joconde_3_4,
        R.drawable.joconde_4_1, R.drawable.joconde_4_2, R.drawable.joconde_4_3,R.drawable.joconde_4_4,
};



public ImageAdapter(Context c, int ...pos){
    mContext = c;
    //Added this line...
    retuning= new Integer[pos.length];
    for(int i=0;i<pos.length;i++){
        if(i<mMona.length-1){
            retuning[i]=mMona[pos[i]];
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return retuning.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return retuning[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mMona[position]);
    return imageView;
}
}
```

In your Activity Class call this Adapter as follow..

```
int []img={0,2,3,5};
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,img);
gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, tried this code but it throws a NullPointerException on this line

retuning[i]=mMona[pos[i]];

Comment: oh.!, sorry. Actually i missed to initialized the `retuning` array in the code, now i have edited this code, you may try again.